# how to test the relevant row in the db table has been locked using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have one table and i locked it using id for update.

```
select name from tablename where id=2 for update
```

how can i test the relevant row in the db table has been locked.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the row with `id=2` exists, you can use:

```
select name from tablename where id=2
for update skip locked
```

If the result is empty, it means the row is locked by another user (or it doesn't exist).

You could also use:

```
select name from tablename where id=2
for update nowait
```

If the row exists, and is locked by another user, then the query will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Is for learning or training purposes, and if not what you are trying to accomplish?

Open two connections (using "psql", for example), and in each one run:

```
begin; select name from tablename where id=2 for update;
```

The second one should block until the first one does either a rollback or commit.  This blockage is the evidence of the lock.  There are many variations, one or the other or both could be doing an actual UPDATE, rather than a SELECT...FOR UPDATE.